# Computing distance matrix for data table of 26000 rows and 5 columns leads to memory error

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do hierarchical clustering with a data table that isn't too large and has only numerical data.

```
> dim(user_info_scaled)
[1] 26497     5
> d = dist(user_info_scaled)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.6 Gb
```

Also I have this info:

```
> tables()
     NAME                 NROW NCOL MB COLS                                                                             KEY
[1,] user_info         149,676   35 66 V1,run,endo.x,V1.x,_id.x,country,gender,weight,height,temperature.x,humidity.x,w                        
[2,] user_info_scaled   26,497    5  2 height,weight,ascent.x,duration.x,hour_start_per_run
```

Why am I getting this error? I understand that a distance matrix is n squared, but I still don't see how that gets me to a 2.6 Gig vector. What am I missing?

Comment: `dist` doesn't take n^2, but just the lower triangle of the distance matrix, since it's symmetric and the diagonal is zero. That nx(n-1)/2 times 8 bytes per numeric element. Using Google as my calculator, I get 2.8 GB: https://www.google.com/#q=2808258048+bytes+in+GB You should be in that ballpark, anyway. Sounds like you need to get more RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an R object will take up about 2.5Gb of RAM. Here's what it uses on my Linux box with 64Gb of RAM.

```
> obj2 <- dist(matrix(rnorm(26000 * 5), ncol = 5))
> print(object.size(obj2), units = "Gb")
2.5 Gb
```

It's not storing the whole `n` by `n` object (which would need ~5Gb of RAM), just the lower triangle of the matrix, hence the difference. Each element uses 8 bytes IIRC and you are storing 337 *million* of them.

This is just the size of the object as far as R is concerned; you might need more RAM to create it. The error is saying that R requested 2.6Gb **more** RAM at some point in the operation using `dist()` and this could not be allocated by the OS